# Three atomic forms expression both in disjunctive and in conjunctive form?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

we know that A v B is in both conjunctive and in disjunctive normal form.

we also know that A ^ B is in both conjunctive and in disjunctive normal form.

Does it follow from this, that A v B v C  is in CNF and in DNF

and that A ^ B ^ C is in CNF and in DNF?

And could we continue this infinitely?

(we can put the parentheses there if we want and as we want)

Thanks!

Comment: See [Conjunctive Normal Form of Any Statement](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Conjunctive_Normal_Form_of_Any_Statement)

Comment: Could you please answer the question? Are both A v B v C and A ^ B ^ C both in CNF and DNF? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I don't know that A v B is in conjunctive normal form.

Here's a definition of a clause adapted from Merrie Bergmann's An Introduction to Many-Valued and Fuzzy Logic p. 20:

1. A literal (a letter or negation of a letter) is a clause.
2. If **P** and **Q** are clauses, then (**P**∨**Q**) is a clause.

Definition of conjunctive normal form.

1. Every clause is in conjunctive normal form.
2. If **P** and **Q** are in conjunctive normal form, then (**P**∧**Q**) is in conjunctive normal form.

Here's a definition of a phrase from p. 18 of the same book.

1. A literal is a phrase.
2. If **P** and **Q** are phrases, so is (**P**$\land$**Q**).

And disjunctive normal form:

1. Every phrase is in disjunctive normal form.
2. If **P** and **Q** are in disjunctive normal form, so is (**P**$\lor$**Q**).

Now, A, B, and C are all phrases, as well as clauses by condition 1. of both definitions above.  Thus, A, B, and C are in conjunctive normal form and disjunctive normal form, and (A$\land$B) and (A$\lor$B) are in disjunctive normal form, and conjunctive normal form.  Now, C is a clause and thus in conjunctive normal form by the above.  So, since C and (A$\land$B) are in conjunctive normal form, so is [(A$\land$B)$\land$C].  Similarly, one can show that [(A$\lor$B)$\lor$C] is in disjunctive normal form.

If we subscript literals, A$_1$, ..., A$_n$, then by an inductive argument we can show that ((A$_1$$\land$A$_2$)$\land$...A$_n$) is in both conjunctive normal form and disjunctive normal form... at least once the parenthesizitation becomes clear.

Comment: Ok, I see. There is only one thing left I don't understand in your answer:
You say: "Actually, I don't know that **A v B is in conjunctive normal form**."

And then you say: "Thus, A, B, and C are in conjunctive normal form and disjunctive normal form, and (A∧B) and **(A∨B) are in disjunctive normal form, and conjunctive normal form.**"

Does it contradict or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: @user3435407 There is no contradiction in what I said.  All CNFs and DNFs which are not literals have parentheses around them (unless we rewrite the definition of a CNF or DNF in prefix or postfix notation or use a different infix notation... which goes something like if **P** and **Q** are in conjunctive normal form, then (**P**)$\lor$(**Q**) is in conjunctive normal form).